# Issues with selecting #text inside an html, div enclosed in double quotes using xpath/lxml in python

Tags: python, html, xpath, lxml, screen-scraping

I'm trying to extract the Fund Summary text on the following [Yahoo Finance page](https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/quote/VUN.TO?p=VUN.TO) using python:

Thus far, XPath has worked well using the XPath with the `text()` method. However it is seemingly unable to select this particular text, always outputting an empty array `[]`.

I've tried the following xpaths:

- `tree.xpath("//*[@id='Col2-4-QuoteModule-Proxy']/div/div/div/text())`
- `tree.xpath('//*[@data-yaft-module="tdv2-applet-fundSummary"]/div/div/text()')`

Is there something about the #text that needs to be targeted differently? The first XPath I used there was copied directly from inspect element.. so I'm not sure how else to select it.

Comment: Does the page contain/show the data in the browser if Javascript is disabled? These days lots of content in a web page is loaded dynamically with Javascript, so a parser like lxml which loads a static HTML document without running Javascript willl not have any data loaded by Javascript.

Comment: Yes it is still showing when I disable JS.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific, are you trying to find this value in the main page or inside a market?
Most of the time all the information you need is sent inside a json or a script, try searching for the values you are looking for inside the HTML or json response and extract them from there

Comment: The response of a plain request to the site contains a script with the variable "App.main" wich contains a JSON with all the information listed in the summary.
If you are looking to extract live data a better solution would be to capture the websocket responses from wss://streamer.finance.yahoo.com/

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

```
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# get the page
r = requests.get('https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/quote/VUN.TO?p=VUN.TO')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

# find the script we want
js_delimiter = 'App.main = '
for s in soup.find_all('script'):
    if js_delimiter in s.text:
        myS = s.text
# load it as a json
js_variable = json.loads(myS.split(js_delimiter)[-1].split(';\n')[0])

# now js_variable contains all the content of the page
print(js_variable['context']['dispatcher']['stores']['StreamDataStore']['quoteData']['VUN.TO']['regularMarketPreviousClose']['fmt'])
```